# Should I condemn a church that might be teaching wrong doctrine?

Tags: church-local

I used to attend one church which felt quite weird for me. Here are a few things that I don't agree with:

- Everybody can speak in tongues. The steps are, first you need somebody to pray with you so you are being baptized by spirit, after that, you can just speak gibberish as long as it make some sounds that will be called as speaking in tongues. They have a session during the worship for speaking in tongues only and they also speak in tongues after prayer.
- According to them, church leaders must be rich. There was once the preacher speaking about a  poor pastor and he said that God didn't anoint him to become a pastor and that's why he's poor.

These are things that bothered me and I stopped going to that church. But my question is, should I condemn them? Or could it be another method that God uses to reach out to more believers?

Comment: What do you mean by "condemn?" Unless you're a dictator or on a jury, it's doubtful that you mean anything besides "ignore" or "tell my friends to stay away."

Comment: Humility is a really good start here. Just sayin'